# Read line by line, validate schema to Json file, display error message

Tags: python

I'm New to Python & started, unable to get code work

Requirement is to read the Json file line by line in Python and
Perform Validation and then display the Error message for any error on data, data type. Also validate code should display the line where It failed

Tried with following code but it’s not working:

```py
import json    
import jsonschema    
from jsonschema import validate    

with open('F:/Join.json') as fp:    
    cnt = 0
    for line in fp:
        a=line    
               
    def get_schema():
        with open('F:/Ab.json', 'r') as file:   
            schema = json.load(file)    
    return schema    

    def validate_json(a):
        execute_api_schema = get_schema()    

    try:    
        validate(instance=a, schema=execute_api_schema)
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as err:     
        print(err)    
        err = "Given JSON data is InValid"    
        return False, err    

    message = "Given JSON data is Valid"    
    return True, message    
    print(a)    
    # validate it    
    is_valid, msg = validate_json(a)    
    print(msg)    
    cnt += 1
```

Source that needs to taken into consideration
Have used three records

```
    {"votes": {"funny": 2, "useful": 5, "cool": 1}, "user_id": "jak", "name": "jak", "url": 
    "http://example.org/user_details?userid=jak", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 10, "type": 
     "user"}
    {"votes": {"funny": 1, "useful": 2, "cool": 4}, "user_id": "Lak", "name": "Lak ", "url": 
    "https://www.example.com/user_details?userid=Lak", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 10, 
    "type": 
    "user"}
    {"votes": {"funny": 1, "useful": 0, "cool": 4}, "user_id": "Jill", "name": "Jill", "url": 
    "https://example.com/user_details?userid=Jill", "average_stars": 3.5, "review_count": 10, "type": 
    "user"}
```

Expectation
Script should validate the json data, schema & only present the error message &
also the line number

Schema used for the Json file

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "votes": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "funny": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "useful": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "cool": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "funny",
        "useful",
        "cool"
      ]
    },
    "user_id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "url": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "average_stars": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "review_count": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "votes",
    "user_id",
    "name",
    "url",
    "average_stars",
    "review_count",
    "type"
  ]
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing with your current script?

Comment: When you say "it's not working" - producing an unexpected result, or you're getting error messages? And have you copied your code incorrectly, or is your indentation like that in your script? For example in your first function everything needs indenting by 4 spaces (as does a lot of other stuff in your code)

Comment: Also please don't bother with "can someone please assist" - the point of stack is to ask questions and the people will answer and try to help. Questions should serve primarily as documentation for others to reference when they come across similar issues - so there is no need for please and thank you (although it's friendly it's actively discouraged on Stack)

Comment: Says None is not a type of object as first error, not sure how to bypass this error to read contents and validate json

Comment: Please fix your indentation. The code as it is right now cannot work baécause of the wrong indentation

Comment: Hi Fredric, have edited the code now, hopefully it should be okay, but the code is't working as per the requirement i mentioned

Comment: Your program still does not look correctly aligned. is the function definition inside the for loop or outside? If inside, then it should be right indented. Your try except statements are also not indented correctly.

Comment: For each line read from `'F:/Join.json'`, you are calling the `get_schema()` function. If `get_schema()` is going to do the same thing again and again, why call it many times. Why not have the data available globally so you can reference it inside the function? Or pass the schema as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Going through your requirement , I see you might be getting the below error :

[image]

This is due to mismatch of defined schema object structure to the json file which we passed to validate . The best approach is to define the array of object in the schema for properties field as , you are passing an array of elements in the json sample .

The indentation and script looks good but we need make sure the schema is matching with script structure.

Note : Please do have a look into your schema validation using (Draft7Validator.validate) to get a confirmation about your schema being correct one .